# Delay windows shutdown by 30s by default

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

By default, shutdown expected to be delayed for 30s at all the time shutdown is initiated.

Google drive sync up app needs little time to push to cloud after my Dad closes his local excel file and shuts down. Sometimes he forgets that he need to give sometime before shutdown and file not getting uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a small batch file saved on the desktop & double-click that rather than use the 'Start' menu method.

Microsoft documents the entire syntax for `shutdown.exe` [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown) but the only parts you really need to know are `/s` to actually invoke the shutdown & `/t` to implement a timer.

Your batch file can be as simple as `shutdown.exe /s /t 30`
That will shutdown in 30 seconds from the time you launch the batch file.

To make a batch file, all you need is to start in Notepad with a new txt file, then when you save, name it 'myShutdown.**bat**'. Having .bat instead of .txt will allow it to run by double-clicking.